# Populate Drop Down List based on multiple user roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I am trying to populate a `DropDownList` based on roles. I have a view in `SQL` with the value and text of each item based on the user role (Windows Auth) and can populate the `DropDownList` if a user was in all roles with:

```
 using (var db=new GPSE_2.DAL.GPSE2Entities())
            {
                var locations = (from loc in db.LocationLOBViews
                                orderby loc.LocationNumber
                                select new { loc.DataValue, loc.DataText});
                ddlShops.DataValueField = "DataValue" ;
                ddlShops.DataTextField = "DataText";
                ddlShops.DataSource = locations.ToList();
                DataBind();
            }
```

I would like to add items only the logged in user is a member of. Users can be in multiple groups(roles).

For instance, the logged in user is in a group called `Location 01 LOB 100` and they are also in a group called `Location 01 LOB 200` and also in `Location o2 LOB 100`. Only those options should appear in the `DropDownList`.

I was able to loop through the roles the user is in by the code below.

```
string UPN = UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName.ToString();
                WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(UPN);
                string GroupName;
                foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
                {
                    GroupName = group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
                    if (GroupName.Contains("Location 01 LOB 100"))
                    {
                        var item = new ListItem
                        {
                            Text = "Location 01 LOB 100",
                            Value = "01,100"
                        };
                        ddlShops.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
```

Now I am trying to combine the 2 I ran into problems adding loc.DataValue and the loc.DataText to the DDL if the query returns results. This is where I an stuck, it adds the string in the quotes instead of the values.

```
using (var db = new GPSE_2.DAL.GPSE2Entities())
{
    string UPN = UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName.ToString();
    WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(UPN);
    string GroupName;
    foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
    {
        GroupName = group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
        var locations = (from loc in db.LocationLOBViews
                         where loc.DataValue.Contains(GroupName)
                         orderby loc.LocationNumber
                         select new { loc.DataValue, loc.DataText });
        if (locations !=null)
        {
            var item = new ListItem
            {
                Text = "DataText",
                Value = "DataValue"
            };
            ddlShops.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

-Doug

Comment: The only way to get role information is to query active directory directly for each user.  You'd probably do better knowing the list of roles in advance, and filtering it down based on whether the user is part of it or not using the IsInRole method you show.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating a list of groups the user is in and then populating the Drop Down List with the appropriate information.

```
    private List<string> GetGroups()
    {
        string UPN = UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName.ToString();
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(UPN);
        foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
        {

            string GroupName = group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
            //if text location and lob is in the name add to results
            if (GroupName.Contains("Location") && GroupName.Contains("LOB"))
            {
                string DataValue1 = GroupName.Substring(GroupName.Length - 3);
                string DataValue2 = GroupName.Substring(GroupName.Length - 10, 2);
                string DataValue = DataValue2 + "," + DataValue1;
                result.Add(DataValue);
            }


        }
        result.Sort();
        return result;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (var db = new GPSE2Entities())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < GetGroups().ToArray().Length; i++)
                {
                    string DataValue = GetGroups().ToArray()[i].ToString();
                    var locations = (from loc in db.LocationLOBViews
                                     where loc.DataValue == DataValue
                                     orderby loc.LocationNumber
                                     select loc).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (locations != null)
                    {
                        var item = new ListItem
                         {
                             Text = locations.DataText,
                             Value = locations.DataValue
                         };
                        ddlShops.Items.Add(item);
                    }

                }

            }
            ddlShops.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Location and LOB--");
        }
    }
```